# Propositional logic in prolog almost works, trouble with xor

Tags: prolog

I'm very new on prolog, so I'm trying to make a propositional logic solver, something who solves this:

[image]

The idea is to pass the p,q,r,s boolean parameters when consulting like this (just by example):

```
solvelogic(true,true,false,true).
```

So I have this knowledge base:

```
implies(X,Y) :- (not(X);Y).                       %that's implies formula and it works
xor(X,Y) :- not(X=Y).                             %that's xor formula and it works too
and(X,Y) :- X,Y.
or(X,Y) :- X;Y.

implies1(P,Q,R) :- implies(and(P,Q),R).
implies2(P,Q,R) :- implies(P,(or(not(Q),R))).
implies3(P,Q,R) :- implies(implies1(P,Q,R),implies2(P,Q,R)).
```

So I can test if my code works by consulting:

[image]

And it's ok for now, but lets try with the final xor, who takes the entire proposition that I need:

[image]

It returns true and that's wrong because if `implies3(true,true,true)`returns true, so `xor(implies3(true,true,true),true)` **should return false**, but it doesn't.

I can prove that xor(X,Y) works:

[image]

That's correct, it returns **false**, but I don't know what's happening when I consult `xor(implies3(true,true,true),true)`, it should return "false" but it doesn't, even when that's the same than xor(true,true).

What could be the problem? I think I'm so close!

Comment: The problem is that you are not simplifying. Your `xor/2` does `implies3(true,true,true) = true` which is false, not true.

Comment: I suggest you to write your `xor/2` like this: `xor(A,B) :- or(A,B), nand(A,B).` `nand(A,B) :- not(and(A,B)).`

Comment: thank you very much @damianodamiano, it works! What's xor/2 by the way?

Comment: @TomasBy implies3(true,true,true) = true, because {ent1(true,true,true)} and {ent2(true,true,true)} returns {true}, so ent3(true,true,true) equals {true -> true}, which is true, not false.

Comment: My `xor/2` works in this way: `or` truth table is `0111`, `and` truth table is `1000`, the comma in prolog works like an `and` so `0111 and 1000 = 0110` which is `xor` truth table.

Comment: @damianodamiano ty for the explanation, it's just I don't know why you and TomasBy are calling xor as xor/2.

Comment: Because in prolog, when you cite a predicate, you usually also write the number of the arguments it takes. So `xor/2` identifies the predicate xor with to arguments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169508/discussion-between-roberto-sepulveda-bravo-and-damianodamiano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to solve your problem you could rewrite your `xor/2` predicate in this way:

```
nand(A,B):- 
    not(and(A,B)).

xor(A,B):- 
    or(A,B), 
    nand(A,B).
```

And the query:

```
?- xor(implies3(true,true,true),true) 
false
```

The implementation of `xor/2` follows this idea: the truth table of `or` is `0111`, the truth table of `and` is `1000` so for `nand` is `0111`. The comma `,` works like an `and` so `0110 and 0111` is `0110` which is the truth table of `xor`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
eval(P,R) :- P -> R=true ; R=false.

%xor(X,Y) :- not(X=Y).                  %that's xor formula and it works too
xor(X,Y) :- eval(X,A),eval(Y,B), A\=B.
```

Note I reified the arguments... and would suggest to revise your code accordingly

Comment: I've tested this and works fine, but Damianodamiano solved my question firstly, and his solution is simpler than this. Anyway should I mark this question as accepted?

Comment: No, because the core of my answer is in suggesting reification. Would require to rethink your code. Thanks for the interesting question, and my compliments for your code. Very nice :)